# Base64 encoded image works in browsers but not in c#

Tags: c#, html, image, base64, gdi+

After acquiring a base64 encoded image from the HTML5 canvas I send the base64 string wrapped as a JSON object to a Generic handler. The handler is supposed to write that string as a binary image into a folder. However, when I try to save the string into a binary image I get the following error:

> An exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: A generic error occurred in GDI+.

But the base64 string seems to work in browsers, by appending "data:image/png;base64," to it at the beginning.

**C# Code:**

```
 String statpath = context.Server.MapPath("~\\UploadedFiles\\" + System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd_HHmmssff") + ".png");
    
    byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(@"iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAUAAAAGQCAYAAADfrrmFAAACB0lEQVR4nO3BMQEAAADCoPVP7WkJoAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAADgBtH5AAHcrK+uAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC");

    Image image;
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
    {
        image = Image.FromStream(ms);
    }
    image.Save(statpath, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
```

It gives me the error when I try to save the image.

The error code it gave me was : -2147467259

**Javascript Code:**

```
canvas.toDataURL('png').replace('data:image/png;base64,','');
```

Note: The image is a blank png (just for testing) so better view it in firefox.

Comment: The Problem have to do with the path. I changed the path to a local path and ist working great. What's the Name of the exception?

Comment: The exception was named 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException'

Comment: Have you already debugged and watched whats the content of your statpath String?

Comment: I have checked the statpath variable the contents are Ok

Comment: @ClaudioP, I changed the path to my documents folder and the code worked. Thanks. I think this is some folder permission based error, which is strange.